# I have a Cat-6 8ft on my motherboard's Intel® GbE LAN chip (10/100/1000 Mbit) but am still only getting 100Mbps

Tags: ethernet, lan, cat6

I have tried changing the speed and duplex to 1Gb however it changes the status to unconnected on the ethernet connection and changing the ports in the wall does not change this. I am on a college campus and am connecting ethernet into wall. My Wifi is running 360Mbps on the same connection (college campus).

Comment: Sounds like the cabling doesn't support gigabit ethernet. WiFi equipment is relatively easy to replace compared to rewiring all sockets.

Comment: Managed network questions are off topic here.

Comment: They are considered as out of topic on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ too ;).

Comment: Managed networks are enterprise networks. That means Server fault. However, OP should go talk with his college IT support first.

Answer (score 2):

If your cable isn't damaged, the origin of the problem is most probably your **college cabled network limitation**.

Ask to the network engineer of your college which speed and mode is available on wall socket Ethernet ports.
Provide him the socket ID you tried since this characteristics could be different for different parts of your college network.
These characteristics depend of the fixed cabling quality, its length, the patch cable used to connect to a switch and the configuration of the switch’s port your connection arrives to.